# How does Spring uses ThreadLocal variables

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, entitymanager, thread-local

I would like to know some details on how Spring uses `Thread local` variables
in managing EntityManagers.

My model is the following:

```
@Transactional
public class MyClass 
{
  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void toSomethingTx()  
    {...}
}
```

Let's consider the class above, wich is a class annotated with `@Transactional` and uses an entity manager,
when the entity manager is injected what is injected is really a proxy class
that looks for the actual entitymanager in the **ThreadScope** to propagate the calls.

This way each thread managing a user request is bound to its own entity manager.

It would be great if you could validate my model and/or add more information   about this.
Thanks

Comment: down-voting for what ?

Comment: Question may be a bit too large I think + put some more code there plz.

Tour page : Requests for lists of things, polls, opinions, discussions, etc.

Comment: I hope I improved the question,thanks.

Answer (score -3):

Spring relay on java ThreadLocal mechanism, see this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html

Note that if you use ThreadLocal in your code you have to manage data erasure when you don´t need it in order to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: if you do a down-vote, please, leave a reason. In this way all learn, thanks!

Comment: Ok, now with code I realized that i did not understand well your question. Sorry